# How do I pass a list of strings as a parameter in CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I've got a nested CloudFormation template which accepts a number of parameters from its root template to configure it. At the moment I'm only passing simple string parameters but now I need to pass a list of S3 bucket ARNs onto the child template.

```
ChildLambdaStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      AwsRegion: !Ref AwsRegion
      Environment: !Ref Environment
      Product: !Ref Product
      S3Buckets: "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1,arn:aws:s3:::bucket2"
    TemplateURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/child-template.yml"
```

And then in the child template I have this

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: "Child Lambda"

Parameters:
  AwsRegion:
    Type: String
  Environment:
    Type: String
  Product:
    Type: String
  S3Buckets:
    Type: String

Resources:
  DeployerPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:DeleteObject
              - s3:CreateBucket
              - s3:DeleteBucket
              - s3:ListBucket
              - s3:PutBucketNotification
            Resource:
              - Fn::Split:
                - ","
                - !Ref S3Buckets
```

My idea is that that list of S3 bucket ARNs that I'm inputting is expanded in the child template like this

```
Resource:
  - arn:aws:s3:::bucket1
  - arn:aws:s3:::bucket2
```

But when I run the template in, it just errors out

```
Syntax errors in policy. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument)
```

I've tried other variations like using a `CommaDelimitedList` parameter type, but none work. Is there a simple way to pass in a list of strings as a parameter?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Because the return value of `!Split` is `A list of string values.` I would do it in the following way:

```
[...]
    Resource: !Split [",", !Ref S3Buckets]
[...]
```

Comment: Is this any different to what OP has done? It's inline, but otherwise it calls the same function with the same arguments, right?

Comment: It's not the same. OP added an extra `-` in front of `Fn::Split` which means it passes a list with a value of list with strings.

Answer (score 19):

As [@MaiKaY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3115607/maikay) points out, the flaw in [@Liam Mayfair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2115499/liam-mayfair)'s code is that `Fn::Split` is preceded by `-` which results in a list containing a single element which is a list. The fixed code would look like

```
...
            Resource:
              Fn::Split:
                - ","
                - !Ref S3Buckets
```

On a more general note, you must make sure to use a Parameter type of `String` not `CommaDelimitedList` when using `Fn::Split` as it won't split a `CommaDelimitedList`.

- If you use `CommaDelimitedList` with `Fn::Split` you'll get the error `Template error: every Fn::Split object requires two parameters, (1) a string delimiter and (2) a string to be split or a function that returns a string to be split`
- If you use `CommaDelimitedList` with no `Fn::Split` you'll get the error `Syntax errors in policy`

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a much better way. You can use the type `List<String>` in your CloudFormation Parameters:

```yaml
# ...
Parameters:
  S3Buckets:
    Type: List<String>
# ...
```

Then pass the S3 Bucket list just like you did as comma separated values:

```yaml
# ...
ChildLambdaStack:
  Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
  Properties:
    Parameters:
      AwsRegion: !Ref AwsRegion
      Environment: !Ref Environment
      Product: !Ref Product
      # Next line will be interpreted as a list
      S3Buckets: "arn:aws:s3:::bucket1,arn:aws:s3:::bucket2"
    TemplateURL: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/child-template.yml"
# ...
```

You can then assume that the type of the referenced Parameter is a list. So instead of:

```yaml
# ...
Resource: !Split [",", !Ref S3Buckets]
# ...
```

You can just use:

```yaml
# ...
Resource: !Ref S3Buckets
# ...
```

Comment: CommaDelimitedList also works for this.